# need to adapt script for mysql

Tags: mysql

```
USE ActivityLog; 
GO 

SETUSER 'dbo' 
GO 

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Events WHERE EventID = 282 AND EV_Event = 'Report Imported') 
BEGIN 
  INSERT INTO dbo.Events 
    (EventID, CategoryID, EV_Event, EV_Template, EV_IsActive, EV_CreationDate) 
  VALUES 
    (282, 6, 'Report Imported', '', 1, GETDATE()) 
END 
GO
```

I want to edit above mentioned script for mysql.

Comment: That seems just lacy.

Comment: What's stopping you from doing so?

Answer (score 1):

I had to remove GO and IF NOT EXIST, GETDATE() is also changed:

INSERT INTO dbo.Events 
    (EventID, CategoryID, EV_Event, EV_Template, EV_IsActive, EV_CreationDate, EV_DmlDate, EV_DmlUserID) 
  VALUES 
    (282, 6, 'Reconciliation Report Imported', '', 1, CURDATE(), CURDATE(), 0)

Thanks!